# How can I search for a string in an array, and then get what comes after same string until a point, in php?

Tags: php, json

EDIT: Parsed the array completely (it contained unparsed JSON!)

```
array(22) {
  [0]=>
array(4) {
["responseData"]=>
array(1) {
  ["translatedText"]=>
  string(163) "21558299 this is the text that i want to end up with, excluding the id number at the start of the string"
}
["responseDetails"]=>
string(0) ""
["responseStatus"]=>
int(200)
```

The string I want to search for is the 2155.. and IFF it's present, I want to get the string that's after it...  How can I do this? Any help much appreciated!  (Or a better solution...?)

**What I need is a return boolean telling me if the ID is actually contained within array - if it is, I need the text. If it's not, I need to know as I want to put some other text (not relevant here).**

Disclaimer: Gonna give this one to nickb, he's been beyond awesome.

EDIT: This part is irrelevant now:

---

This is what I got so far, but it's returning null. $trans_json is the array quoted above. $search[id] is another array, that holds the id string.

```
$return = array_filter( $trans_json, function($el) { 
    if( !( $start = strpos( $el, $search[id]) === false)) {
            $str =  substr( $el, $start);
            return substr( $str, 0, strpos( $str, '}'));
    }
            return null;
    });
```

Comment: It'd be better to parse the JSON and then proceed with finding what you want, instead of this approach.

Comment: i'm sure you are right. but then i'd have to figure out how to parse inside an array, and quite frankly, i don't know how.

Comment: yeah, regular expressions are a nightmare :p

Comment: @KnutOle: code is always more useful than data dumps, since the former can be used directly but the latter must be edited by hand. To that end, you can use [`var_export`](http://php.net/var_export) instead of `var_dump` to get sample data. Please edit your question and replace the dump with a PHP parseable array representation.

Comment: @outis: easy for you to say! :P but yes, i will try. and i agree. can't believe i just spent an hour on this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_walk()`](http://www.php.net/array_walk):

Your example isn't working because `$search` is undefined. You need a closure (note the `use ($search)`:

```
$search['id'] = '2s5d56b9712';
$return = array_walk( $trans_json, function( &$el) use( $search) { 
    if( !( ($start = strpos( $el, $search['id'])) === false)) {
        $str =  substr( $el, $start);
        $el = substr( $str, strlen( $search['id']) + 1, strpos( $str, '}'));
    }
});

var_dump( $trans_json);
```

Comment: also, it's a BIG array, 200kb perhaps. so maybe i am better off parsing it first after all? should i open a new Q for that in that case?

Comment: @KnutOle - No. It's not working because you can't just put `$search` in.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use a closure, which is what you need.

Comment: are you sure this is right? sorry to ask, but i don't understand why it doesn't work! thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: ah, great! sorry, refresh issue :) i'll try it now.

Comment: @KnutOle - I meant array_walk, not array_filter. Try this now, [it works in my test](http://codepad.viper-7.com/r0Sykl)

Comment: thanks a lot nickb! i really appreciate your help, and it's all on me for not knowing my stuff better: but it seems that if the ID is not found, there is no way of knowing? ($return returns true anyway.) and that it doesn't work over multidimensional arrays? (i manage to reproduce in codepad, but not locally where i've got an array (32). and that there are 17 extra characters at the end (=length of id), which i dont know how to get rid of.

Comment: anyway, i'll parse the array, as it seems it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

See code below if it suits your need.

```
<?php

$subject = 'array(32) { [0]=> string(3266) "{"respString":{"feedbackText":"2s5d56b9712 the preceding id is the string i want to search for, and this is the rest of the text i want to get until here:"},"blablaarraycontinues...';

preg_match("/feedbackText\":\"2s5d(.*)\}/",$subject,$matches);

print_r($matches[1]); // output the matched string

?>
```

Comment: actually, the id string is entered as a variable, so kinda hard to do regex on it. really appreciate the effort though - and yes, my blood goes cold when i see regex's!

Comment: Well the above answer is a working code. I actually matched the string you requested.